# Any ideas how to make this FOR LOOP? VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, vb.net-2010

Any Ideas on how to make this to *"FOR LOOP"* because the number of data that I want to show is not fixed or constant so I need to make it into for loop.

```
 Public Sub ReportTransactionsLogs(ByVal LV As ListView)
                Dim rReport As New ReportTransLog
                Dim row As DataRow = Nothing
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                ds.Tables.Add("TransactionsLog")

                With ds.Tables(0).Columns
                    .Add("Username")
                    .Add("ActionDate")
                    .Add("ActionTime")
                    .Add("Activity")
                    .Add("POInvoice")
                End With

                For Each LVI As ListViewItem In LV.Items
                    row = ds.Tables(0).NewRow
                    row(0) = LVI.Text
                    row(1) = LVI.SubItems(1).Text
                    row(2) = LVI.SubItems(2).Text
                    row(3) = LVI.SubItems(3).Text
                    row(4) = LVI.SubItems(4).Text
                    ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(row)
                Next


                rReport.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
                ReportViewer.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rReport
            End Sub
```

Comment: Not clear, this loop works on every ListViewItem, why do you need to replace it with a for..loop?

Comment: because my column names are not fixed, sometimes it will be different, and sometimes the number of the columns that I wanted to show is not constant

Comment: I don't understand how this can be sql-server tagged

Comment: Because the data of the listview came from SQL SERVER.. So it though that might helps

Answer (score 0):

try like this..

```
For Each LVI As ListViewItem In LV.Items  row = ds.Tables(0).NewRow

  For i As Integer = 1 To ds.Table(0).Columns.Count()
    If InlineAssignHelper(i, 0) Then
        row(i) = LVI.Text
    Else
        row(i) =LVI.SubItems(i).Text
    End If
   Next

Next
```

Comment: Where can i get the InlineAssignhelper?

Comment: its like : 
if(i==0) then
 row(i) = LVI.Text
end

i convert it from somewhere that's its showing it, i'm not familiar with vb.net.